# Perl Excel::Writer, how to format a cell with date category

Tags: excel, perl, date

I need to make a cell in date format (for italians it's Data category).
I've searched around but everyone tell:

```
my $date_format_1 = $workbook->add_format( num_format => 'dd/mm/yy' );
$worksheet->write_date_time( 'A1', '2013-10-27T', $date_format_1 );
```

but this is not true: this one make the cell as "format: personalized"... i need "format: date".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This should work according to the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm#DATES_AND_TIME_IN_EXCEL), but

```
my $date_format_2 = $workbook->add_format( num_format => 'dd/mm/yy' );
$worksheet->write_date_time( 'A1', '2013-10-27T', $date_format_1 );
```

contains a typo.

You are actually using `$date_format_1` instead of `$date_format_2` .

Comment: Well spotted. Welcome to the Perl tag. :)

Comment: I told you that it doesn't work... so your answers is wrong.

typo corrected.

Comment: @Zak did you give the plain 'write' method a try?
`$worksheet->write( 'A1', '2013-10-27T', $date_format_1 );`

Comment: @Zak Did you play around with the examples of the Excel::Writer Module? There are two files you should take a look at: _date_time.pl_ and _formats.pl_ .
I've used the module before, just never did use it for dates.
If I got time I'll give it a go during the weekend.